# Understanding the generators of the Möbius band homology group $H_1(M)$ through singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

After contemplating the responses to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614338/understanding-relation-between-a-map-in-a-short-exact-sequence-of-chain-complexe/4614354#4614354) question (and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308273/central-circle-of-mobius-band-generates-first-homology) one too), I was wondering how to understand why the Möbius band has the center circle as a generator through *singular* homolgy (seeing as this is the theory Hatcher relies on before reaching example 2.47 in his book *Algebraic Topology*):

**It's supposed to be generated by a singular $1$-simplex that is also a cycle. How can I see there is just one such singular $1$-simplex and that it must be the center circle?**

Comment: I believe the sketch here is: (1) show that the center circle has homology generated by one singular 1-cycle (this boils down to showing that this is just true for $S^1$), (2) the inclusion induces an isomorphism on homology since the inclusion is a homotopy equivalence (on account of the deformation retraction of the Mobius band to the center circle). Theoretically, by the time you get to 2.47, step (1) is something you believe. Unless this isn't what you're asking?

Comment: It *can* be just one singular 1-simplex and it *can* be the center circle. There is no *must* in this business... you can always replace a $1$-cycle by itself plus a nonzero $1$-boundary, and you'll get a different $1$-cycle representing the same homology class.

Comment: @LeeMosher Right, thanks. So in the linked responses why can't the chosen basis be the $S^1$ by which they are attached instead of the center circle? (thus leading to $1 \mapsto (1,-1)$ instead of $1 \mapsto (2,-2)$? (I'm getting the hunch that I am misinterpreting one of these circles, but I'm not seeing which one and how...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the generator of $H_1(M)$ for $M$ the Möbius band simply *can* be taken to be a singular $1$-cycle, since a cycle plus boundary gives a new cycle that's the same in homology.

Your second question in a comment boils down to saying "Why can't the (homology class of the) boundary circle of the Möbius band be taken as the basis element for $H_1(M)$?"

Since $\partial M$ is homeomorphic to a circle, this circle is itself a $1$-cycle, so denote the generator of $H_1(\partial M)$ by $[\partial M]$. Saying that this generates $H_1(M)$ amounts to saying that the inclusion $i: \partial M \to M$ induces an isomorphism on homology, since wanting the boundary circle of the Möbius band to generate $H_1$ means that you want $[i(\partial M)] = i_*[\partial M]$ to generate $H_1$.

Now, consider the composite $\partial M \xrightarrow{i} M \xrightarrow{r} C \to M$, where $r$ is the deformation retraction onto the center circle $C$ and the last map is the inclusion of $C$ into $M$.

If $i_*[\partial M]$ generates $H_1(M)$, then $r_*(i_*[\partial M])$ is twice the generator of $H_1(C)$ since $\partial M$ wraps twice around $C$, and since the inclusion of $C$ into $M$ induces an isomorphism on homology, this composite sends $1 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 2$. On the other hand, $M \to C \to M$ is homotopic to the identity map, so this composite should end in $1$, not $2$. This gives a contradiction.